# If expression not evaluating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a for loop where I'd like to print some page content based on an if statement evaluation. It seems the expression in the if statement is not being evaluated, since none of the branches print out the content.

```
//evaluates to True
<%: (ViewData["project_id_PO"] as List<int>).Contains(4) %> 

//doesn't evaluate
<% if((ViewData["project_id_PO"] as List<int>).Contains(4) == true){ 
        Html.Raw("<p>Test1</p>");
    }
    else
    {
        Html.Raw("<p>Test2</p>");
    } %>
} %>
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: why not use a strongly typed model?

Comment: and you need to write the response. you aren't doing that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by writing the response. Can you elaborate. I have multiple active links above this code and they print.

Comment: Anything in special for not using Razor since you're using MVC4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the expression in the if statement is not being evaluated, since none of the branches print out the content.

This is an incorrect assumption.

`<% %>` code blocks excecute the code but don't explicitly write anything to the output stream.

I believe what you are trying to achieve is the following

```
<%= (ViewData["project_id_PO"] as List<int>).Contains(4) 
    ? Html.Raw("<p>test1</p>")
    : Html.Raw("<p>test1</p>") %>
```

Using the `<%=` renders the output to the stream.

However you are better off creating a ViewModel for this purpose rather than doing calculations in the View.